# Adding Textfields to scroll view programmatically?

Tags: swift, xcode, scroll, view, textfield

I am trying to add a textfield to a scroll view and outlet collection on button press, how am i to do this?

Can't seem to find my answer elsewhere.

Comment: Why would you have an outlet collection if you add them programmatically?

Comment: The first few textfields are added from storyboard, if more is needed they can be added via a button press in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add it in the beginning, have it hidden, and bring it forward on the button press by either changing the .isHidden attribute or changing .alpha.

If you want to reposition other elements in the view when it's unhidden, you can add layout constraint outlets and activate new ones each time the button is pressed.